# what are +/- for socket.io vs ajax for uploading files?

Tags: file-upload, websocket, socket.io, scalability, high-availability

I heared that the websockets (e.g. **socket.io**) are very fast, but they require direct connection for each client.  Is it so sutable for uploading files for video hostings **with many clients**/ **frequently** uploads? Or will it fail and only **ajax** can be used in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the file sizes and how long connections to clients last.

If you chunk uploads using the HTML5 FileAPI, then use Websockets to upload the data, this can dramatically reduce the amount of data transferred because they don't need to send HTTP headers with every request; these can add up if for example you split a 1GB file into 5MB chunks.

If clients are persistently connected then Websockets can reduce the need to do long polling, wasting resources on your server if there is no new information to push to the client.

Websockets will therefore reduce the resources required but they are not available on every browser.